# Cartogram not working: "Cancelled by user" - Why?

Tags: qgis, cartogram

I am using the [QGIS Cartogram plugin](https://github.com/informeren/qgis-cartogram), but unfortunately something is not working as it should.

First, the demo works just fine. But when I want to create a cartogram with my own layer. But as soon as I click „ok“, it says 
"Cartogram creation cancelled by user“.

Do you have a clue, what I'm doing wrong? What am I canceling?

Comment: Could you please add which version of QGIS you are using? I can confirm this works for QGIS 2.8.2-Wien for Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there zeros or null cells in the desired collumn of the attribute table? I had this problem last week and solved adding a different value to these cells

Comment: +1, you are right in that it gets cancelled if zeros or `NULL` values are present.

Comment: It looks like the development version has fixed this by providing more informative error messages: https://github.com/informeren/qgis-cartogram/issues/4